# Angular2 select form not capturing value

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

I'm using Angular 14 trying to create a select form reading the options from an array in my component.
The select options are correctly populated, but when I send the form, the selected option value is not being sent.  It just keep it empty.
Any suggestions about what could be causing this?

```
<mat-label>Perfil</mat-label>
    <mat-select name="perfil">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let perfil of perfis" 
       [value]="perfil.value">{{ perfil.title }}
       </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

In the component the array is:

```
  perfis: {title: string, value: number }[] = [
      { "title": "Admin", "value": 1 },
      { "title": "Coordenador", "value": 2 },
      { "title": "Colaborador", "value": 3 },
    ];
```

Inside form component's constructor:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [''],
    login: [''],
    password: [''],
    nome: [''],
    rg: [''],
    cpf: [''],
    telefone: [''],
    email: [''],
    ativo: [''],
    perfil: ['']
  });
```

To submit the form:

```
onSubmit() {
console.log(this.form.value); // this is where I see the field is always empty
this.usersService.save(this.form.value)
.subscribe(
  data => this.onSuccessInsertion('Informação inserida do banco de dados.'),
  error => this.onError('Não foi possível salvar esta informação no banco de dados.')
  );
```

}

Maybe I'm listing the options but I'm not capturing the value after being selected? If so, how should I do this? I've read that you could use [selected], but that was not even recognized by Angular.

I noticed that maybe it is because the value is being captured as a string. I read in another post that [value]="..." only supports string values and
[ngValue]="..." supports any type
So it would be needed to use [ngValue]="perfil.value" in the HTML, but it gives me error if I [ngValue] instead of [value].
The error message is:

> Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'.

1. If 'mat-option' is an Angular component and it has 'ngValue' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-option' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.ngtsc(-998002)

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console ?

Comment: Can you share the parts of you code where you create the form object and also where you send it ?

Comment: Thanks for replying.
No specific error in console. Only a:
users-form.component.ts:69 POST http://localhost:8080/users error 400
Because my backend will refuse saving empty content.
Will add the part of the form code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the select is not associated with a control in the `FormGroup`. Because of this, Angular doesn't know that the select should change the `perfil` control in the form. Assuming you set the `FormGroup` earlier in the template, you can bind the select to that control with the `formControlName` directive, like this:

```
<mat-select name="perfil" [formControlName]="'perfil'">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let perfil of perfis"
    [value]="perfil.value">{{ perfil.title }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```